# How to pops last list?

Tags: python, list

How to pops last list in list 2d Because I try **A[].pops** it's not working.

```
Before I pops:
*A[[1],[2],[3]]*
```

```
After I pops:
*A[[1],[2]]*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use normal `pop`

```
A = [[1],[2],[3]]
A.pop()
print(A)
```

```
[[1], [2]]
```

```
A = [[1],[2],[3]]
A[-1].pop()
print(A)
```

```
[[1], [2], []]
```